# how to format using formulas in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet in which Column N cells/Range of cells need to be formatted by any interior color using the condition

```
AND(OR(ISBLANK(N1),N1>M2),E1=E2)
```

Kindly suggest how implement this in VBA. I tried to get this by recording macro, but not getting any code for this.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
If Range("E1").Value = Range("E2").Value Then
    If (Len(Range("N1").Value) = 0) Or (Range("N1").Value > Range("M2").Value) Then
        MsgBox "The conditions have been met"
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error YowE3K. I have amended the code's syntax.

Comment: I've done a quick edit to just use normal code formatting, and to insert the missing bracket.  (You still had `Len(Range("N1").Value = 0`.)